# CakePhp :: How to set up logger for easy debugging?

Tags: cakephp

How to set up logger in cakePhp?

i want to print the parameters which is passed to the controller? how can i do that in cakePhp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write to log file:

```
$this->log($this->params, 'debug');
```

For more info: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html

Comment: i have done by referring there.. but din not get what happening under the hood. in which file i will see the printed messag?

Comment: there was a file error.log.. i have created new one called debug.log

Comment: it prints [2012-04-09 16:19:06 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class CssController could not be found.
#0 C:\xampplite\htdocs\cakephp\app\webroot\index.php(96): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}}

Comment: It sounds strange. When you do `$this->log($this->params, 'something');` Cake automatically creates file named `something.log` in the log directory. `MissingControllerException` and similar should appear in `error.log`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to print parameters then:

```
debug($this->params);
```

would do it. You can use it in AppController within a function and calling that function in specific controller action.
Hope that helps